# mongoose finding records with multiple conditions and checking if the request parameter not empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm new to this technology and working with Node and Express server that uses Mongoose and MongoDB 3.3 . I have following schema for a document collection.

```
exports.schemaLivre = new mongoose.Schema({
    Id : Number,
    Nom: { type: String, maxlength: 50 },
    Auteur: String,
    Description: String,
    Categorie: String,
}
exports.Livre = mongoose.model('Livre', schemas.schemaLivre);
```

I'm trying to run a web service having 3 parameters .

```
app.get('/Livres/search=:search&category:=category&auteur=:auteur', controller.RecupererLivresMultiple);
```

each parameter can be empty and foreach parameter I have a different kind of search logic ( for the param search , I will use regex expression to check through "Nom" and "Description" and "Auteur" fields in the same time, for category and auteur , the value submitted must be equal to the content of the field).
I will need something like that but I didn't found the right query .

```js
exports.RecupererLivresMultiple = function (req, res) {
    var re = new RegExp(req.params.search, 'i');

    models.Livre.find($and: [ 
        { 
            $or: [
                { 'Auteur': req.params.auteur }, 
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [ 
                { 'Category': req.params.Category }, 
            ]
        }
    ]).or([{'Nom': {$regex: re}}, {'Auteur': {$regex: re}},{'Description':{$regex: re}}]).exec(function (err, livres) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        res.json(livres);
    });
};
```

The question is How to check the request parameter sent from the web service is empty and How I disable it in my query when searching for records .
My second question is how to combine those logic of search together ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the basic structure you want for your query is:

```
{
    'Auteur': req.params.auteur,
    'Categorie': req.params.category,
    $or: [
        { 'Auteur': re}, 
        { 'Categorie': re}, 
        { 'Nom': re}, 
    ]
}
```

To make each parameter optional, you can do something like this to build the query:

```
// create empty query
var findJSON = {
};

// append criteria if parameters present
if (req.params.auteur){
    findJSON.Auter = req.params.auter
}
if (req.params.category){
    findJSON.Categorie = req.params.category
}
if (req.params.search){
    var re = new RegExp(req.params.search, 'i');
    findJSON.$or = [
        { 'Auteur': re}, 
        { 'Categorie': re}, 
        { 'Nom': re}, 
    ];
}

models.Livre.find(findJSON).exec(function (err, livres) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
        res.json(livres);
});
```

Because each parameter is optional, you should handle the case where none is provided.  You could do:

```
if(req.params.auteur || req.params.category || req.params.search){
    models.Livre.find(findJSON).exec(function (err, livres) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        res.json(livres);
    });
} else {
    res.json([]);
}
```

You may also want to handle the error condition differently.  As you have it now, you aren't actually writing to the response if your find() returns an error.